# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES access to all schemas and tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a user that should only have access to the database tables metadata,via INFORMATION_SCHEMA, and not the table data.  So no perms to query the tables directly. The role the user will be a member of will have USAGE privileges on INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema. I tested the user with that role and it is only able to see tables within public and no where else.

I did see in Snowflake documentation:
"The output of a view or table function depend on the privileges granted to the user’s current role. When querying an INFORMATION_SCHEMA view or table function, only objects for which the current role has been granted access privileges are returned."

So, I tried to grant to the role MONITOR and USAGE on other schemas; but, that did not work either.  Only when I granted a role with read access to all the tables in the schema was it able to see and query from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES the tables in that schema.  This, however, is not what I want as now that user would be able to query data from the tables.  I just want to set that user to be able to query and gather the metadata of tables and not allow data access.  Is there a way in Snowflake to setup and perform this type of setup?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this would be to provide access to the `SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE` share on Snowflake, which also has `TABLES` and would allow this user to query the metadata of all tables and columns in that Snowflake account.  There is a lot more information available in that share, but at least the user would not have access to any real data, if that is what you are after.