# Snowflake JDBC driver "select on each table to ingest" permission

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-permissions

I am connecting to Snowflake from Collibra through the Snowflake provided JDBC driver.

My objective is to extract tables, columns metadata of a schema in Snowflake and load that metadata into the Collibra Catalog.

However, a deeper look at the permission "select on each table to ingest" that must be given to the user who connects to snowflake is a worrisome thing for us. The technical user can select data from the tables like any other user. Is there any way to avoid the permission?

Br,
Noor.

Comment: Just to make sure we understand what you mean - can you link to the relevant docs?

Comment: The technical user created in snowflake that Collibra is using to extract metadata is executing the below statements in snowflake (i.e. SHOW command which seems to be requiring the SELECT permission on tables): show /* JDBC:DatabaseMetaData.getSchemas() */ schemas in database ""ABC""
show /* JDBC:DatabaseMetaData.getSchemas() */ schemas in database ""ABC""
show /* JDBC:DatabaseMetaData.getTables() */ objects in database ""ABC""
show /* JDBC:DatabaseMetaData.getColumns() */ columns in database ""ABC""

Comment: Here is the link (we can find the permissions under "Minimum user permissions
" section) ---> https://productresources.collibra.com/docs/cloud-user/2021.04/#cshid=DOC0761?catalog-connector-details=data-sources/catalog-connectors.snowflake

Comment: There is already a post on the exact requirement I have now but the suggestion there from Mike is not marked as "answered". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62272292/information-schema-tables-access-to-all-schemas-and-tables